# Unable to smoothly stream video

Tags: ssh, vlc-media-player

I have an SSH server set up at home, which has a bunch of hdd's connected to it, storing a large collection of media. Before, it was just a media server for home, and the SSH was for configuration, but after downloading SFTP Net Drive, I can access these files remotely.

Now, when I try to view one of my videos, it plays in VLC, but only for a few seconds before pausing for a much greater period of time while it buffers. Only problem is, it doesn't make sense. I am at the moment copying the file to my computer to play it from there, but it is transferring at about 400KB/s, and copied in 8 minutes. The video is 30 minutes long.

After a cursory calculation, VLC is reading the file at 70KB/s, which would make sense as the the videos data rate 714kbps. But during playback, this figure wildly fluctuates.

So, is there a way to "convince" VLC (if thats where the problem lies) to fetch the file at a higher rate than what the file specifies, so that I can play the files without downloading them first?

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that the issue is teh SFTP. can you use a sharing system less focused on crypto, like Samba or some form of http streaming (rtsp, etc)?

Comment: Not over the public internet, but I doubt its to do with SFTP as I can use SFTP to transfer the file at 400KB/s, consistently. I'm testing other media players, but compared to VLC, well, lets just say theres a reason I use VLC

Comment: It plays fine in Windows Media Player